# Handling unnecessary self-promotion

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion

I was looking through some recent posts when I came upon [this one in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456244/android-locale-doesnt-work).  I noticed the user put a link to his application, which is completely unnecessary for the question, so I flagged it.

I guess my own error was flagging it as spam, which in retrospect was a little harsh, but that leads me to my question:

How should have I treated this?  Would just editing out the reference have been better or should I just leave it there?  Or maybe there's a better flag to file it under.

[This discussion from SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers) says there's nothing overtly wrong with self-promotion as long as it's on-topic, but in this case I don't feel it is.

Comment: Well, you flagged your example link. I presume that's why the link is now dead! :))

Comment: Oops "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

Comment: @BentTranberg I forgot to mention my flag was marked as unhelpful, haha

Comment: So when SO goes public to monetise the site, what do we do? Flag the shareholders?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this case, I don't see this as *overt* self-promotion; it is just one link in one question. The reference is irrelevant, just edit it out.

Comment: It's definitely *overt*, he's not trying to hide the fact that the application behind the link is his.  Whether it was self-promotion or provided just in case the appstore description/metadata affected answers is harder to say.