# Why did I fail this VLQ review audit? It's not VLQ, NAA, spam, abusive, a comment, or a thank you

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13993297) review in the VLQ queue and was given a ban for it. I don't understand what is VLQ about the post.

Perhaps the post provided a technologically incorrect answer to the OP's question, but [that is not what VLQ means and such answers should be downvoted instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302802/why-was-this-vlq-flag-disputed). Since it makes a bare-minimum attempt, however ineffectual, incompetent, or downright incorrect, to resolve the OP's question, it is [not NAA and should be downvoted rather than flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  Even though the post includes a link, the link is used to provide further reference rather than to provide a primary answer, [meaning that it is not a link-only answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). The post wasn't abusive. One might suspect that the answerer was trying to promote their blog (or a blog that they are affiliated with) and that the answer should be treated as spam, but [some level of self-promotion is allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261806/handling-unnecessary-self-promotion), and [blogs are no exception if the answer actually is an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273209/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-your-own-blog). The answer is not a "thank you" post, nor is it a comment.

Can someone help me understand?

The question [Review audit: Answer marked as spam, unclear why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289277/review-audit-answer-marked-as-spam-unclear-why) doesn't really answer my question because it is not clear that the post referenced there was as content-heavy as the one I am talking about and it doesn't actually explain how to detect the difference between an arguably unnecessary link and a spam link, it only asserts that such a difference exists.

Comment: FYI, it was deleted by a moderator via delete vote (so it's not spam or rude/abusive). Also, it's interesting that [a First Posts review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13833196) for this answer was completed as "No Action Needed".

Comment: This was a clear attempt at spamming the site via the link at the end of the post. The answer is just click bait. As well, we **require** users to disclose their affiliation with a site or product when linking to it as a reference to their answer.

Comment: @animuson how do you know this? Or, more specifically, how can one tell the difference between link spammers who actually provide an answer and non-spamming answerers who cite blogs in their answer?

Comment: @animuson where would I have gone to determine if the answerer had an undisclosed affiliation with the site they were linking to?

Comment: @animuson Then why wasn't it flagged as spam?

Comment: @Gothdo It was, by four people. As were two of his other answers. The moderator just didn't cast a spam flag himself. Probably because he didn't realize this was a pattern for this user (hence why the user got destroyed afterwards).

Comment: @animuson so if the moderator didn't notice the pattern, how should I have recognized it, especially if the user is deleted and I can't view their other posts? If a user is deleted, that doesn't automatically mean that everything that they have ever posted is spam. The user could have been deleted for unrelated conduct such as abusive posts.

Comment: @RobertColumbia We don't choose audits based on a user's deletion state. It's completely irrelevant. The post was chosen because it has several spam flags marked as helpful from members of our community who *did* see that the post was spam and flagged as such.

Comment: @animuson so how should I have been clued in to mark the post? I can't view others' spam flags on a post. I'm not questioning whether it *is* spam, only whether or not the audit gave me fair warning that it *was* spam.

Comment: Neither can other users. They were all cast independent of each other without knowing the others existed. But looking at the URL is a pretty big clue. Just in general, including "seo" in the domain name is a pretty huge red flag for a very common tactic frequently employed by SEO spammers. Coupled with the fact that the answer was years late and provided no new information that wasn't already included, and some information that wasn't relevant at all to the question at hand.

Comment: @animuson where are these guidelines documented in the review guide?

Comment: We can't document *every single* behavior of the site. We'd end up with a book that no one would read. There's plenty of information about this stuff around Meta. But no one goes through and reads every single thing on Meta before reviewing. Instead, they learn through experience.

Comment: As a side-note: this answer was caught by the [SmokeDetector bot](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) and reported to various chat rooms. That URL [has already been used multiple times as spam](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=http%3A%2F%2Fseowebsitedesigning.com%2F&username=&why=&site=&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search).

Comment: @animuson it's time to fix that http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/213575

Comment: @animuson so you are saying that the audit model is to keep reviewers in the dark and set them up to fail?

Answer (score 7):

Be very suspicious of new users posting new answers to old questions that contain links to odd websites. I'll quote [my answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334123/how-is-this-answer-spam/334133#334133):

> This is a common pattern of spam that we see on a regular basis.
>   Someone will come here, post short answers that are usually based on
>   or directly plagiarized from existing posts or sites, and then tack on
>   a link to their site at the end. The content at their site is
>   typically plastered with ads or a direct promotion for their products
>   or consulting services, and is usually plagiarized from somewhere
>   else.
>
> Common signals to look for are
>
> - new users whose only posts are short answers with "for more details: [link]" at the end,
> - commercial websites that you've never heard of and that appear nowhere else on Stack Overflow,
> - all of this user's other posts all linking to this site,
> - links to blogspot.in blogs (90+% of these posts originate from India) that you can see from the URL were created the day the answer
>     was posted, and
> - these being new answers to questions asked years ago and answered multiple times already.
>
> Be very wary of new answers to old questions that end with links like
>   this. If in doubt, take a look at the user account and see what other
>   answers they've left. Review is the primary means of identifying these
>   spammers, so please be on the lookout for them when reviewing Low
>   Quality Posts and Late Answers.

In this case, the user was linking to "seowebsitedesigning.com". A new user linking to a site with "seo" in the title should be an immediate red flag, which is why multiple spam flags were cast on this. Even without seeing other posts by this user, I would have flagged this as spam.

Comment: "A new user linking to a site with 'seo' in the title should be an immediate red flag" Why?

Comment: @dorukayhan - Because it's almost always spam. Black hat SEO folks mistakenly think that they can boost their pagerank by spamming links in questions and answers here, and try to do so every day. It's one of the reasons the [seo] tag is [such a trash fire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334707/provide-asking-instructions-for-seo). There's no way that a site about SEO has any relevance to a pure CSS question, like the one asked here.

Comment: Actually, if you go to the SEO site linked, it does in fact have an article on CSS that might arguably be considered helpful for the OP. Perhaps it is not the best CSS article out there, and perhaps an article from a dedicated CSS site or a more highly reputed site would have been a better cite (no pun intended), but it is at least marginally on-topic for the question. It is a much different situation from an answer that spams a link for knockoff handbags, herbal supplements, or something else that is entirely off-topic for the question.